# Google Geocode Returns Wring Address

Tags: geocode

I am using the Google geocode API and the results I receive are almost always accurate, except when they are not.  For exampe, the URL:  https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&key=mykey&address=107%20Vandiver%20Rd%20Lot#13,Allenhurst,GA,31301 returns a completely different area of the country (listed below).  The same address returns: 107 Vandiver Rd #13
Allenhurst, GA 31301 on Google Maps.  Any idea as to what I a doing wrong?

Returns:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<type>premise</type>
<formatted_address>107 Vandiver Dr, Madison, TN 37115, USA</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>107</long_name>
<short_name>107</short_name>
<type>street_number</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Vandiver Drive</long_name>
<short_name>Vandiver Dr</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Madison</long_name>
<short_name>Madison</short_name>
<type>neighborhood</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Nashville</long_name>
<short_name>Nashville</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Davidson County</long_name>
<short_name>Davidson County</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Tennessee</long_name>
<short_name>TN</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>United States</long_name>
<short_name>US</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>37115</long_name>
<short_name>37115</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>4242</long_name>
<short_name>4242</short_name>
<type>postal_code_suffix</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>36.2632706</lat>
<lng>-86.6781400</lng>
</location>
<location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
<viewport>
<southwest>
<lat>36.2619304</lat>
<lng>-86.6795023</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>36.2646284</lat>
<lng>-86.6768044</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
<bounds>
<southwest>
<lat>36.2632156</lat>
<lng>-86.6782322</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>36.2633432</lat>
<lng>-86.6780745</lng>
</northeast>
</bounds>
</geometry>
<place_id>ChIJ_XkNqMtDZIgRQYGJVL6WQro</place_id>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not url encoding the '#' in 'Lot#13'

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&key=mykey&address=107%20Vandiver%20Rd%20Lot%2313,Allenhurst,GA,31301 will work fine.